# how to make fake URL in apache site?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have apache site, lets say with the domain `example.com`.

I also have a directory `example.com/test`.

I would like to make anyone who enter the URL`example.com/test` to see a fake URL, For example: instead of `example.com/test` he will see `site.com/page.html`

**Not a redirect**, just change the URL, is it possible?

Comment: You used the right tag "mod-rewrite" I wonder why you can't find anything on the internet....there are mega tons of examples and tutorials for that topic

Comment: The problem is that I canno't use .htaccess because I'm using zend framework, and when ever i put the [P] tag to keep the url, I get error. so I'm trying to put it the in apache site configuration file.

Comment: I don't see how does ZF preclude you from using .htaccess?

Comment: format and style

Answer (score 0):

There is an inherent problem with what you are attempting to do:

1 - user requests example.com/test

2 - user is redirected to example.com/page.html

3 - server shows user the page.html URL but tries to server /test

Now, to achieve step 3 the server will effectively request /test, just like the user did.

This will then cause the same redirect as in 2 and thus lead to 3 again.

So you end up in an infinite loop, which Apache will detect, kill and serve up a 500 status code (too many redirects).

What you need to do instead is this:

1 - change the URLs on your site to page.html

2 - add a RewriteRule to serve up the /test resource:

`RewriteRule ^page\.html test`

Comment: So I created a folder /test and also created .htaccess inside /test, with this line: RewriteRule ^page\.html test
it didnt do anything..